# How to use revoke_ingress method of boto3 to remove a particular security group from inbound rules

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-security-group

I want to delete particular security sg-yy group from the inbound rules of another security group sg-ZZ using  [revoke_ingress](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.SecurityGroup.revoke_ingress) method boto3

source: sg-ZZ
target: sg-yy

I tried:

```
    response = security_group_source.revoke_ingress(
        FromPort=FromPort,
        GroupName=groupName_source,
        IpPermissions=[
            {'ToPort': ToPort,
             'UserIdGroupPairs': [
                 {
                     'Description': description_target,
                     'GroupId': group_id_target,
                     'GroupName': groupName_target,
                     'VpcId': VpcId_target,

                 },
             ]
             },
        ],
        SourceSecurityGroupName=groupName_source,
        SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId=owner_id_source,
        ToPort=ToPort,
        DryRun=True
    )
    print( response )
```

But I am getting error:  An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the RevokeSecurityGroupIngress operation: The security group 'sg_group_name' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-1111'

I can not use:

```
security_group.revoke_ingress(
    IpPermissions = IpPermissions,
)
```

as I need to delete a specific security group

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Are you sure that all your SGs are in a default vpc?

Comment: @Marcin No they are not in default VPC and I am mentioning the VPC it is in
i.e.  `VpcId': VpcId_target`. Also, security group sg-yy and sg-ZZ are in same VPC

Comment: The error says "does not exist in default  default" so its search them in default vpc. Also don't know why you use both `GroupId` and `GroupName`? Should use one of these. For non-devaulf vpc only `GroupId` should be used based on the docs: `For a security group in a nondefault VPC, use the security group ID.`

Comment: @Marcin Even if I use only `group ID` I am getting the same error
and what could be the potential cause that it is looking in default VPC and not the one I am mentioning i.e `VpcId_target`?

Comment: Have to check docs. I see that `GroupName` and `SourceSecurityGroupName` are also only for `[EC2-Classic, default VPC]`. So have to specify other parmaters, or remove them? Not sure of top of my head now.

Comment: Please look at
[Cannot revoke_ingress for non-default VPC with boto3
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316455/cannot-revoke-ingress-for-non-default-vpc-with-boto3) Hope it helps you..
r0ck

Comment: @r0ck As I have mentioned in the question I can not use ```security_group.revoke_ingress(
    IpPermissions = IpPermissions,
)``` As I need to delete a specific security group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be resolved by keeping correct parameters. It is not clearly specified in the Boto3 document what parameters to use for non default VPCs but solving through the errors worked for me.
Working code for non default VPC:

```
       response = security_group_source.revoke_ingress(
            GroupId=group_id_source,
            IpPermissions=[
                {'FromPort': FromPort,
                 'IpProtocol': IpProtocol,
                 'ToPort': ToPort,
                 'UserIdGroupPairs': [
                     {
                         'GroupId': group_id_target,
                         'VpcId': VpcId_target,
                     },
                 ]
                 },
            ],
            DryRun=False
        )
```